# SMJobBless is for Privileged Helper tool, but what if I want to have launchd plist to get copied to /Users/<user>/Library/LaunchAgents

Tags: macos, cocoa, smjobbless

SMJobBless is for Privileged Helper tool, but what should I do if I want to have launchd plist to get copied to `/Users/<user>/Library/LaunchAgents`. I do not want to enter any user password to install the helper tool.

Answer (score 0):

Your app should already be able to create `launchctl` processes and have write access to `/Users/<user>/Library/LaunchAgents`, so can't you just do it directly instead of trying to use `SMJobBless()`?